Error when R package rredlist cannot find a species
This code allows me to get the IUCN status of a species of bird:
remotes::install_github("ropensci/rredlist")
library("rredlist")

c("Branta") -> genus

c("bernicla") -> sp

rl_species_latest(genus, sp)$red_list_category$description$en

# Least Concern

But when I add more species to be queried I get an error. I think this occurs when the species cannot be found. When a species is not found, can it just add NA to the vector instead of returning an error?
c("Branta", "Branta", "Branta", "Branta", "Branta", "Anser", "Anser", "Anser", "Anser", "Anser", "Anser") -> genus

c("bernicla", "ruficollis", "canadensis", "leucopsis", "hutchinsii", "rossii", "caerulescens", "anser", "fabalis", "brachyrhynchus", "serrirostris") -> sp

rl_species_latest(genus, sp)$red_list_category$description$en

# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : 
  URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL: URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function


The help file doesn't seem to suggest that the function is intended to be vectorised - maybe you need to run it in a loop, or use Vectorize() (Not able to verify as the example seems to require registering for an API key)

FYI, using the -> operator for assignment is making your code unnecessarily hard to read, especially when the value is long (in your second piece of code). That’s why there’s a wide consensus not to use this operator.

I'm the maintainer of the rredlist package, and I can confirm that these functions are not designed to be used for vectors of values. I'll add some error handling so it's clearer in the next release. In the future, please feel free to report issues like these on GitHub: https://github.com/ropensci/rredlist/issues.
